# Curve fitting to connect certain points

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, graphing-functions, machine-learning, interpolation

[image]

Well the image says everything, anyone has any idea how to, or where should i look to be able to draw the BLACK curve ?

in fact i need a function that would connect the summits of these red dotted triangles, and it should look like the black curve

Comment: What is the significance of the blue curve?  Why are the interpolation points represented as triangles?  How do they affect/constrain the black curve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images doesn't say much to me, let alone everything.

There are plenty of functions connecting the summits of the red dotted triangles. If you know their coordinates, perhaps you could use them for [Lagrange interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial). I don't know whether the result will look like the black curve, though I doubt it will. Where did you come across this image?

Comment: i am developping a machine learning algo. and i need a variable that takes the values describing the black curves

Comment: lagrange interpolation won't do it for me i guess, i need a way to connect two certain points going through a third point in the middle that i can define

Comment: That is exactly what Lagrange interpolation allows you to do.

Comment: actually i know about it and usually use it, i know it helps, i was just looking for a dirty fast way of doing this, for repetitive reasons actually

Comment: And i especially need to go through a point in the middle usually lower than the points i am gonna connect, and i really need to define the value of that point, something i can hardly see the Lagrange interpolation do

Comment: once again i could do it with the lagrange interpolation i am just looking for a diff method, maybe easier and faster to impliment

Comment: Again, if you define the coordinates of that point 'in the middle', then Lagrange interpolation obviously gives you a curve passing through that point. Unfortunately I don't know any easier or simpler method to find such a function than Lagrange interpolation.